# Export Hibernate data to SQL Statements?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

how can I export Hibernate data to SQL statements, so that I might reimport them.
The data consists of mapped Entities, with Strings, Enums, Integers etc.

I would need an export like: insert into XX (...)

Or similar which I could easily rewrite.
Is there anything I could use yet?

ty

Comment: Can you be more specific . What kind of data you want to use?

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you looking for but you can look this section 10.9 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable query logging by putting

`<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>`

it will print all the statements executed by hibernate,
that you can reuse. I normally use that to verify queries in my toad.

Comment: I tried this before, but the problem is it prints out eg `insert into (..) values (?, ?, ?)` so I still have to fill the fields manually.

Comment: Two ways you can solve this issue, either enable logging for parameter binding and check which parameter values are binded to sql statements. Or else You can use p6spy and configure it as your proxy database driver. It will print all the executed sql statements with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to migrate you data to another MySQL server you should be using mysqldump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html